# Is there any way to make xTile work with MonoGame?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am currently in the process of planning and developing a game. I use MonoGame as my framework, and I also planned to use xTile with [tIDE](https://colinvella.github.io/tIDE/) to manage my tiles, but it *only* works with XNA 4.0, but my project (of course) only references the MonoGame.Framework and not the Microsoft.Xna.Framework, which means that some classes are defined in assemblies which are not referenced.

I know MonoGame is a continuation of Xna, but as the Assembly has a different name/ID, xTile of course doesn't recognise it.

Is there any way to support xTile when using MonoGame? If there isn't, is there any alternative to xTile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using MonoGame with [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) and for parsing I have adapted [TiledSharp](https://github.com/marshallward/TiledSharp) to fit my needs better. But it works out of the box very well.

There is also the MonoGame.Extended project to support Tiled directly.
Long story short: You should switch to Tiled since it's quite popular.